# AMI sharing across Accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami, amazon-imagebuilder

I have created the image in dev (acct-id - 1111111) and need to use the same image on prod (22222222) (same region). But i'm getting the following error. Image is build on Dev workspace and then use it in PROD workspace. Dev is working without any issue, I have AWS::ImageBuilder::DistributionConfiguration configured with launch permission configured for those two workspaces.

```
WEBAutoScalingGroup - AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup - CREATE_FAILED - API: autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup Not authorized for images: [ami-02adsdsw4d8216f7b0a]
```

My Image builder permission as follows.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: image builder policy

Parameters:
  Dev:
    Default: 11111111111
    Type: String
  Prod:
    Default: 22222222222
    Type: String
    
Resources:
  ImageBuilderpolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Description: Extra permission for Image builder role 
      Roles:
        - EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilder
      PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:  
              # s3 get object permission for image builder
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:Get*
                  - s3:List*
                Resource: 
                  - "arn:aws:s3:::dev-imagebuilder-cicd/*"
                  - "arn:aws:s3:::dev-imagebuilder-cicd"
                

#Imagebuilder policy to cicd role
  IAMPolicyEC2ImageBuilder:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - CICDRole
      Description: Policy to access AWS EC2 Image Builder Service
      ManagedPolicyName: 'EC2ImageBuilderIAMPolicy'
      Path: '/ImageBuilder-Management/'
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'imagebuilder:CreateComponent'
              - 'imagebuilder:CreateDistributionConfiguration'
              - 'imagebuilder:CreateImage'
              - 'imagebuilder:CreateImagePipeline'
              - 'imagebuilder:CreateImageRecipe'
            Resource: '*'
            
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'imagebuilder:CreateInfrastructureConfiguration'
            Resource: '*'
            
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'imagebuilder:CancelImageCreation'
              - 'imagebuilder:Get*'
              - 'imagebuilder:DeleteComponent'
              - 'imagebuilder:DeleteDistributionConfiguration'
              - 'imagebuilder:DeleteImage'
              - 'imagebuilder:DeleteImagePipeline'
              - 'imagebuilder:DeleteImageRecipe'
              - 'imagebuilder:DeleteInfrastructureConfiguration'
              - 'imagebuilder:ImportComponent'
              - 'imagebuilder:StartImagePipelineExecution'
              - 'imagebuilder:TagResource'
              - 'imagebuilder:UntagResource'
              - 'imagebuilder:UpdateDistributionConfiguration'
              - 'imagebuilder:UpdateImagePipeline'
              - 'imagebuilder:UpdateInfrastructureConfiguration'
            Resource: '*'
            
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'sns:Publish'
            Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*imagebuilder*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: iam:PassRole
            Resource:
            - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:instance-profile/EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilder
            - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilder
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                iam:PassedToService: ec2.amazonaws.com
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole
            Resource: arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/imagebuilder.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForImageBuilder
            Condition:
              StringLike:
                iam:AWSServiceName: imagebuilder.amazonaws.com
          - Effect: Deny
            Action:
            - ec2:RunInstances
            - ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile
            Resource: "*"
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                ec2:InstanceProfile: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:instance-profile/EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilder

  Ec2ImageBuilderCrossAccountDistributionAccessPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - CICDRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: "ec2:CreateTags"
            Resource: "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "ec2:DescribeImages"
              - "ec2:CopyImage"
              - "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute"
            Resource: "*"

  EC2ImageBuilderDistributionCrossAccountRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: EC2ImageBuilderDistributionCrossAccountRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: 
                - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${Dev}:role/aws-service-role/imagebuilder.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForImageBuilder
                - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${Prod}:role/aws-service-role/imagebuilder.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForImageBuilder
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"

      Policies:
      - PolicyName: EC2ImageBuilderKMSInlinePolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: 
                - 'kms:Encrypt'
                - 'kms:Decrypt'
                - 'kms:ReEncrypt*'
                - 'kms:GenerateDataKey*'
                - 'kms:DescribeKey'
                - 'kms:CreateGrant'
                - 'kms:ListGrants'
                - 'kms:RevokeGrant'
                - 'ec2:CreateLaunchTemplateVersion'
                - 'ec2:ModifyLaunchTemplate'
                - 'ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates'
                - 'ec2:CreateTags'
              Resource: '*'
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - ec2:CreateLaunchTemplateVersion
                - ec2:ModifyLaunchTemplate
              Resource: "*"
              
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates
              Resource: "*"
              
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - ec2:CreateTags
              Resource: arn:aws:ec2:*:*:launch-template/*
              
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref Ec2ImageBuilderCrossAccountDistributionAccessPolicy
```

Not sure why it's failing with "Not authorised for images" error.

Comment: What are the permissions that the autoscaling has?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Image Builder is relevant to solving the problem that you are having. When you create AMI, you need to [share](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html) it with Account 222222. If you are building AMI with Image Builder pipeline, just add `aws ec2 modify-image-attribute` command to the pipeline

For testing, before using AMI in autoscaling group, try to launch an instance from it in prod account. If you *can't* - solve this problem first.